# How to fix: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: linux

This error is not showing if I don't give the path for curl and if I give the path for curl this error comes
`CPPFLAGS='-I/home/dhanraj/project/netcdf/c/hdf5/include -I/home/dhanraj/project/netcdf/c/zlib/include -I/usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz/include' LDFLAGS='-L/home/dhanraj/project/netcdf/c/hdf5/lib -L/home/dhanraj/project/netcdf/c/zlib/lib -L/usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz/lib' ./configure CFLAGS="-o3" --prefix=/home/dhanraj/project/netcdf/c/netcdf`

```
configure: netCDF 4.7.0
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: checking user options
checking whether a NCIO_MINBLOCKSIZE was specified... 256
checking for valgrind... no
checking if fsync support is enabled... no
checking if jna bug workaround is enabled... no
checking whether we should build netCDF-4... yes
checking whether we should build with HDF5... yes
checking do we require hdf5 dynamic-loading support... yes
checking whether reading of HDF4 SD files is to be enabled... no
checking whether to fetch some sample HDF4 files from Unidata ftp site to test HDF4 reading (requires wget)... no
checking whether we should attempt to install netcdf-fortran (EXPERIMENTAL)... no
checking whether parallel IO tests should be run... no
checking whether a user specified program to run mpi programs... mpiexec
checking whether a default chunk size in bytes was specified... 4194304
checking whether a maximum per-variable cache size for HDF5 was specified... 67108864
checking whether a number of chunks for the default per-variable cache was specified... 10
checking whether a default file cache size for HDF5 was specified... 4194304
checking whether a default file cache maximum number of elements for HDF5 was specified... 1009
checking whether a default cache preemption for HDF5 was specified... 0.75
checking whether netCDF-4 logging is enabled... no
checking whether nc_set_log_level() function is included (will do nothing unless enable-logging is also used)... yes
checking whether DAP client(s) are to be built... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/dhanraj/.local/share/Trash/files/netcdf-c-4.7.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Still not working after CFLAG="O3"

Comment: It says `See 'config.log' for more details.`. So, find the line in the `config.log` file that includes the sentence `checking whether the C compiler works` and post the lines after that.

Comment: configure:4723: checking for gcc
configure:4739: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4750: result: gcc
configure:4979: checking for C compiler version
configure:4988: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4999: $? = 0
configure:4988: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc "Thanks for the help"